# How to do split() by counting the number of unknown len() in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have python script to check user online or offline, but i have trouble.

```
useron=u', '.join(useron)  
useroff=u', '.join(useroff)  
if useron:  
    repon+=u'ONLINE\nUser: '+useron+u'.'  
if useroff:  
    repoff+=u'OFFLINE\nUser: '+useroff+u'.'  
reply(type, source, repon)  
reply(type, source, repoff)
```

The problem is I can not be sure how many users are on and off while the maximum limit of each time sending messages only 150 characters of letters, I try to split() with count the number of len() on the message, but always failed.

I want to try if the first message the number of letters exceed 150 characters, then the remaining messages will be continued in the second message then the third message and the next message.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear, can you please explain what exactly you are trying to split and count `len()` for, Example input/output for your program would be helpful.

Comment: i try to split repon and repoff if more than 150 character of letters.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input and output..? and desired output too?

Comment: all input i call with useron and useroff, and output with repon and repoff, my full script is too long, but the output just use reply

Comment: i call useron and useroff with .join()

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly - you can only send a maximum of 150 characters in each command; and you want to make sure you split the commands correctly so that you don't violate the character limits and the commands make sense.

To do this, you need to be a bit clever in how you organize your commands. Store the command along with the length in a list, then sort the list and then split it into chunks where the length is closes to 150.

Try this:

```
login = []
logout = []

for user in online_userlist:
    cmd = u'ONLINE\nUser: {}'.format(user)
    login.append((len(cmd), cmd))

for user in offline_userlist:
    cmd = u'OFFLINE\nUser: {}'.format(user)
    logout.append((len(cmd), cmd))
```

Now, you want to send out the commands in even chunks of 150 characters here is one way to do it (hint: can you see if you can optimize it?):

```
command = ''
for length, cmd in logout:
   if len(command) + length < 150:
     command += cmd
   else:
     reply(type, source, repon)
     command = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string based on the length, then you should use `subscript` (indexing) rather than `str.split()` .

Example -

```
useron=u', '.join(useron)  
useroff=u', '.join(useroff)  
if useron:  
    repon+=u'ONLINE\nUser: '+useron+u'.'  
if useroff:  
    repoff+=u'OFFLINE\nUser: '+useroff+u'.' 
for i in range(0,len(repon),150):
    reply(type, source, repon[i:i+150])
for i in range(0,len(repoff),150):
    reply(type, source, repoff[i:i+150])
```

---

Example/Demo (to print in blocks of `5` for simplicity) -

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklm"
>>> for i in range(0,len(s),5):
...     print(s[i:i+5])
...
abcde
fghij
klm
```

Comment: brother, thanks to response, i will try, your advice looking possible to success.